# How to export raw audio from audacity?

Tags: filters, audio, filter-design, lowpass-filter, audio-processing

Request to Experts:

I am a DSP novice. I would like to experiment with some methods for low pass filtering in the time domain.

To that purpose, I would like to generate a tone in audacity and export it as a raw file (without headers), then process it using simple C/Java file handling programs (without using audio processing library), and then import it back into audacity and listen to it and plot its spectrum.

However, I am unable to find a way to export raw audio from audacity. Could you please guide me if/when free?

Comment: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/export.html#:~:text=To%20export%2C%20choose%20File%20%3E%20Export,a%20selected%20area%20of%20audio ?

Comment: Click File/Export/"Export as WaV"

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for guidance. I would like to avoid headers since I want to try some experiments using simple C/Java file handling programs without the use of a audio processing library.

Comment: @Jdip Thank you. I couldn't find option for raw export in that page or elsewhere in the manual.

Comment: @RiteshSingh: File/Export/Export Audio. Select file type "other uncompressed files",Header: RAW (header less), Encoding: whatever you want there.

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you. Could you please add that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available in File > Export > Export Audio...

[image]